# Passing parameter for launch testing in ros2

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am running launch testing where I have a test node that's used for testing if messages are been transmitted.
When I run individual nodes like `pub_demo` or `sub_demo` it works, it takes parameters from the `config` file. But when I run the `demo_pkg_test.py` using launch_test these two nodes don't take the parameters. Even the test node doesn't take the parameters.

```
src
├── demo_pkg
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── config
│   │   └── params.yaml
│   ├── include
│   │   └── demo_pkg
│   │       └── qos_custom_profile.hpp
│   ├── package.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── pub_demo.cpp
│   │   └── sub_demo.cpp
│   └── test
│       ├── demo_pkg_test.py
```

Below is my code

```
Streaming = QoSProfile(durability=qos.QoSDurabilityPolicy.VOLATILE,
                   reliability=qos.QoSReliabilityPolicy.BEST_EFFORT, history=qos.QoSHistoryPolicy.KEEP_LAST, depth=1)
State = QoSProfile(durability=qos.QoSDurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL,
               reliability=qos.QoSReliabilityPolicy.RELIABLE, history=qos.QoSHistoryPolicy.KEEP_LAST, depth=20)


@pytest.mark.launch_test
@launch_testing.markers.keep_alive
def generate_test_description():

config = os.path.join('/home/'+$USER+'/dev_ws/src/demo_pkg/config/params.yaml')


print(config)
return launch.LaunchDescription([
    launch_ros.actions.Node(
        executable='pub_ex',
        package='demo_pkg',
        name='pub_node',
        parameters=[config]
    ),
    launch_ros.actions.Node(
        executable='sub_ex',
        package='demo_pkg',
        name='sub_node',
        parameters=[config]
    ),
    launch_testing.actions.ReadyToTest()
])


class TestFixture(unittest.TestCase):

def test_pin_robot_enable(self):
    rclpy.init()
    node = Node('test_node')
    self.declare_parameters(
        namespace = '',
        parameters = [
        ('robot_name',None)])
    robot_name = self.get_parameter('robot_name').get_parameter_value().string_value
    print("-------1----",robot_name)
    self.robot_enable_data = []
    sub = node.create_subscription(
        Bool,
        '/sub_topic',
        self.topicMsgData,
        Streaming
    )
    self.pub = node.create_publisher(
        Bool,
        '/pub_topic' ,
        Streaming
    )
    timer_period = 0.5  # seconds
    self.timer = node.create_timer(timer_period, self.pub_callback)
    self.value = Bool()

    try:
        end_time = time.time() + 10
        self.test_data_recv = []
        while time.time() < end_time:
            rclpy.spin_once(node, timeout_sec=0.1)
        
        if self.test_data_recv == []:
            test_data = ""
        else:
            test_data = self.test_data[-1]

        
        self.assertEqual(test_data, True,
                         "Error")
        
    finally:
        node.destroy_subscription(sub)
    rclpy.shutdown()

def pub_callback(self):
    data= Bool()
    data.data = True
    self.pub.publish(data)

def topicMsgData(self, msg):
    self.test_data_recv.append(msg.data)
```

Below is my `params.yaml` file data.

```
pub_node:
  ros__parameters:
    robot_name: "BOT02/"

sub_node:
  ros__parameters:
    robot_name: "BOT02/"

test_node:
  ros__parameters:
    robot_name: "BOT02/"
```

Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402888/passing-parameter-for-launch-testing-in-ros2/) by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2022-06-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2022-06-24**:
can you also post contents of `params.yaml`, it could be something with name mismatch of the node

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2022-06-24**:
@Fetullah Atas Thanks for the quick response. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If anyone comes across the same problem this is how I was able to fix my problem.
There was a mistake in my `def generate_test_description():` function after fixing that my `sub_node` and `pub_node` are able to receive or read the `parameters` from the `param.yaml` file but still, my `test_node` is unable to read the parameters. To fix that part I used the python read file function, just in case anyone wondering how I solved it check this [post](https://answers.ros.org/question/403008/how-to-provide-parameters-for-test-node-in-launch-testing-using-yaml-file-file/).
And the solution to transmit parameters to `sub_node` and `pub_node` nodes that are initiated on `test_node` is as below

```
def generate_test_description():
    config = os.path.join('/home/'+$USER+'/dev_ws/src/demo_pkg/config/params.yaml')
    nodePub = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        executable='pub_ex',
        package='demo_pkg',
        name='pub_node',
        parameters=[config]
        )
    nodeSub = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        executable='sub_ex',
        package='demo_pkg',
        name='sub_node',
        parameters=[config]
        )
    context = {'nodePub': nodePub, 'nodeSub': nodeSub}
    return launch.LaunchDescription([nodePub , nodeSub, launch_testing.actions.ReadyToTest()]), context
```

the missing part was the `context`.

---

Originally posted by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) with karma: 126 on 2022-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After you post params.yaml, I think there is a possibility this is caused by your putting the params in wrong namespace. For example in the launch file, you specify a node name “sub_node” but in yaml file, your specify as “sub_demo”. You need to match the names of nodes in yaml and launch files.

Edit as reply to your comment;

```
sub_demo:
  ros__parameters:
    robot_name: "BOT02/"
```

here your telling that `robot_name` parameter belongs to node with name `sub_demo` , but in the launch file your saying

```
   launch_ros.actions.Node(
        executable='sub_ex',
        package='demo_pkg',
        name='sub_node',
        parameters=[config]
    ),
```

the name of the node is `sub_node`, they are not matching.

---

Originally posted by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) with karma: 819 on 2022-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2022-06-25**:
No all nodes i checked its exactly same

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2022-06-25**:
please see the edit

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2022-06-25**:
sry for the error in the printing. Above code, I modified it for this question during which I made a mistake. But the Node name on my actual code does match.
I did run my test fine and successfully when I don't use and provide the parameter file.
I corrected my question.